# Trying to DELETE Add-Ons that have been added to the G-Suite Market Place

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

We have been developing a Sheets Add-On for the first time and during that process we created a couple of "test" Add-Ons and published them to the G-Suite Market Place. We are now ready to publish the "production" version of the Add-On.

I want to delete those "test" Add-Ons as they may be confusing to the users of the Add-On in our domain. I have contacted Google Support for G-Suite and they have not been able to help with this....

See the screenshots that show the Add-Ons that I want to delete from the marketplace....I have been able to un-publish them but they are still appearing in the listings for our domain as available to install.

Any help on this would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to check this [documentation](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6216211?hl=en)?

Comment: I have seen that and it works for the G Suite Marketplace apps that are installed to our G Suite. But it does not seem to remove them from the listings that are available in the G Suite Marketplace which is what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I work in the G Suite Marketplace. I've asked the Chrome Web Store team and they said they don't support deleting listings, but you can unpublish them.

As you may know we are in the process of migrating G Suite extensions from CWS to GSM (Chrome extensions will remain in CWS). Unpublished CWS listings will not be migrated to GSM and some time after March 10, 2019 we will delete all G Suite extensions from CWS.

For more background, please visit the Chrome Web Store migration page for [editor add-ons](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/cws-migration#if_you_have_multiple_editor_add-ons_sharing_the_same_cloud_platform_project) or for [Drive apps](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/cws-migration). If you have additional questions or need assistance, please contact [CWS migration support](http://cws-migration-support@google.com).

Comment: Thanks for the response....I have already unpublished them. But they continue to show up in the G Suite Marketplace for our G Suite domain. So I was hoping that when I unpublished them that they would not appear.

Comment: Also on the close down for CWS does this mean the Developer Dashboard offered by CWS will also cease

Comment: The synchronization of the backends between CWS and GSM can take up to 2 days. If it is still published in GSM please tell me what the app id is (the number at the end of the GSM URL). Regarding the CWS Dashboard, it will continue to exist, but it will contain Chrome extensions.